# What is a general way to use a Spring project inside another?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data

I have a Spring project which is a regular jar file. It uses JPA and Spring Data.

I'd like to use it in another Spring project, which is a war running in Tomcat. It also uses JPA and Spring Data.

I have installed the jar into the local maven repository, and have declared it as a dependency in the parent project.

What do I need to do to make them work together correctly?

Are there naming conventions for the various context, properties, and persistence files?

Do I need to import the library configuration files in the "parent" configuration files?

I am getting the following error when trying to run the parent:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class [some domain class in the parent project]
```

Comment: Did you try to import the applicationContext files located inside your jar with `<beans:import resource="otherApplicationContext.xml"/>` ?

Comment: Not yet. Is that the general method? Have a distinct name for the applicationContext.xml in the child and import it in the parent applicationContext? What about persistence.xml? Thx

Comment: Not sure if it is the general method but I do it that way when I have 2 or more projects having Spring beans in common. I append a suffix to the shared applicationContext file names (for example: `applicationContext-datasources` and `applicationContext-logs`) and import them inside the main `applicationContext` file of each project : `<import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-logs.xml" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Maven Modules. Reference here:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html